# fullcalendar refresh #calendar after insert data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I am working with codeigniter, bootstrap and fullcalendar

I have a problem with refresh of the calendar after a popup data insert

html code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnCerrarModal2" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnInsertEvento" >Inserisci</button>
</div>
```

js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnInsertEvento').click(function(){
        //var idEvento= $('#idEvento').val();
        var nome = $('#nome').val();
        var dettagli = $('#dettagli2').val();
        var data_inizio= $('#today').val();
        var ore_minuti_inizio = $('#ore_minuti_inizio').val();
        var data_fine= $('#today2').val();
        var ore_minuti_fine = $('#ore_minuti_fine').val();

        $.post("/cubo/users/insertEvento",
        {
            nome: nome,
            dettagli: dettagli,
            data_inizio: data_inizio,
            data_fine: data_fine,
            ore_minuti_inizio: ore_minuti_inizio,
            ore_minuti_fine: ore_minuti_fine
        },

        function(data){
            if(data==1){

                $('#btnCerrarModal2').click();
                //i try to put this without refresh
                //$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I am trying to add this code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
```

But it doesn't work

Can you help me? Thanks a lot I'm a newbie

```
defaultDate: new Date(),
            navLinks: true,
            editable:true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events:$.parseJSON(data),
            eventDrop: function(event,delta,revertFunc){
                    var id = event.id;
                    var data_inizio = event.start.format();
                    var data_fine= event.end.format();
eventClick: function (event,jsEvent,view){
                    $('#mtitulo').html(event.title);
                    $('#testoExtra').val(event.title);
                    $('#idEvento').val(event.id);
                    $('#dettagli').val(event.dettagli);
                    $('#modalEvento').modal();
                    //$('#addEvent').modal();
                },
```

Comment: What does "doesnt work" mean? Using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );` should work if youre using the fullcalendar with properly configured `events` param (e.g. a json feed url, an array or a function (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)).

Comment: @FabianSchöner actually it won't work if you've used an array for `events`, because that's just static data passed into fullCalendar. There's nowhere for the calendar to go to refetch anything. refetch will work if the data source is defined as a URL or a function though, yes.

Comment: @ADyson youre correct. Wouldnt make sense anyways if that wouldve worked cause youll end up with the same "refechted" events.

Comment: @FabianSchöner i get the event from DB, i have a popup to insert data but its doesnt refresh the calendar and i must refresh the page manually

Comment: @ADyson i get the event from DB, i have a popup to insert data but its doesnt refresh the calendar and i must refresh the page manually

Comment: Please show us your full calendar code so we can understand how you populate your list of events

Comment: @ADyson can you give me your email ? i send you the entire code ! you are so gentleman

Comment: No, that's not how this site works. You must post the code inside your question, for everyone to see, so that everyone can help and everyone can learn. That's why it's a community site. Your calendar config cannot be so big that it doesn't fit here.

Comment: @ADyson stackoverflow doesnt allow me to put the entire code ! i know how the site works but there is a lot of codeline ... for this reason if is possible to send you the code in some method email or stack or i dont know , please help me

Comment: You don't need to put the entire code, just the relevant parts. As per the earlier comments, we are interested in your calendar config code, most specifically the bits where you define how the calendar is populated with events. That will  hopefully helpto determine why refetchEvents isn't working for you.

Comment: e.g. I assume somewhere you write something like `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ ....` and within that somewhere you have `events: ....` - it's those bits which are most crucial. As myself and Fabian explained in the earlier comments - "refetchEvents" can only work if you have defined `events:` as being something dynamic - e.g. a URL, or a custom function, which can be used by fullCalendar to go and get a new list of events from the server. If you just gave it a list of data then it cannot ever work because it does not know where to look for the new events.

Comment: @ADyson i update the post with the part that you ask me ;)

Comment: Thanks you. So yes, `$.parseJSON(data)`...this is just a static list of data which you give to fullCalendar. It never gets updated. So "refetchEvents" does nothing, because you didn't tell fullCalendar where to go in order to get new event data. It does not know about any server or database etc, it only knows about the array you gave it originally, and that cannot be changed.

Comment: So, as Fabian's very first comment told you, for refetchEvents to work you must define `events` as either [a URL](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) which returns event data as JSON directly or, if that's not feasible a [function which knows how to fetch the data](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) so fullCalendar knows where to go in order to refresh the data.

Comment: @ADyson  what can i do to give the events of db in fullcalendar ?

Comment: you need to implement either one of the patterns described in the links I gave you in my last comment. have you read those pages yet? Did you understand it?

Comment: @ADyson i read but im newbie of fullcalendar and im not a bigkhauna of JS :) have you some tutorial to follow ?

Comment: No, not off the top of my head. Perhaps you could google it. What specifically are you not understanding though? The events-as-URL example is a particularly simple concept, I would hope.